# ExtJS 4 Panel Grid not loading JSON from a URL - Firefox and chrome doesn't work

Tags: json, extjs

I am using ExtJS 4 and trying to load a JSON file into a Panel Grid. Refer to the code below:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'http://localhost:8180/PatientVisit/grid-patient.json',
        reader: {type: 'json', root: 'patient'}
    },
    fields: [{name: 'PatientId',   type: 'string'}, {name: 'Initial',  type: 'string'}, {name: 'SCStatus',  type: 'string'}, {name: 'V1Status',  type: 'string'}, {name: 'V2Status',  type: 'string'}]
});



var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: 'gridPanel',
    title     : 'Grid example',
    width     : 250,
    height    : 250,
    renderTo  : 'grid-example',
    store     : myStore,
    columns: [
        {    header: 'Patient ID',
            dataIndex: 'PatientId'
        }, { header: 'Initial', dataIndex: 'Initial'}, 
        { header: 'SCStatus', dataIndex: 'SCStatus'}, 
        { header: 'V1Status', dataIndex: 'V1Status'}, 
        { header: 'V2Status', dataIndex: 'V2Status'}
    ]          
});    

myStore.load();

});

JSON file: 

{"patient":[{"PatientId":"M1000","Initial":"MAS","SCStatus":"Complete","V1Status":"Open","V2Status":"Open"},
      {"PatientId":"M573","Initial":"MTZ","SCStatus":"Complete","V1Status":"Complete","V2Status":"Open"},
      {"PatientId":"M634","Initial":"MTS","SCStatus":"Open","V1Status":"Open","V2Status":"Open"}
      ]}
```

It works fine in IE 9. It loads an empty Grid in Firefox 16.x and Chrome browsers. Please let me know if there is an issue with the code above.

Comment: one issue i see is that your store is autoLoad-ed and then you call load() on it again - however that just means you are reloading store. it should still work. perhaps there are other configs or code that is interfering?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. It was a Cross domain AJAX call issue. HTML file was outside the server directory. I make an AJAX call to the server to get the JSON data. Firefox and Chrome doesn't allow this call. IE is allowing and it works fine.